# Is .Net 7 backwards compatible with .Net 6?

Tags: .net

After searching for confirmation on whether .NET 7 is backwards compatible with .NET 6.

I found a Microsoft page which covers [backwards compatibility for .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility) but nothing for .NET Core or subsequent .NET versions.

Having googled the subject I found one post which says it's not and also that .NET 6 will be supported longer than .NET 7.

Neither of these make sense to me.
Could you provide some confirmation of what the situation is?

Comment: On the "6 supported longer than 7" thing - skipping versions for LTS is becoming fairly standard these days.  EG Both Node.js and Ubuntu use this model as well - it means someone can depend on a particular, stable version for a longer time, while the product itself can keep moving forwards for those that want new features, without the product needing to also have/offer LTS for _every_ version.

Answer (score 15):

According to this post - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/7.0 - it doesn't look like it, which makes sense since it's a major version change.

The fact that that .NET 7 will not be supported for as long as .NET 6 will be is a completely separate beast entirely as .NET 6 is a LTS (Long Term Support) release and will be supported with bug and security fixes for (has to look it up) 3 years.

.NET 7 however is a STS (Standard Term Support) release and will only be supported for 18 months (6 months beyond the release of .NET 8).

.NET 8 will be a LTS release and will again be supported for 3 years providing 1 year of overlap in support for .NET 6 and .NET 8.

More info on the support lifecycle of .NET and .NET Core versions can be found here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core

Comment: You're reading it wrong. The linked article talks about what happens to your code if you port it to .NET 7. That's all it says. I'm fairly certain that if you don't touch your code, and target the same (old) .NET version when building, it should load *both* under old and new .NET. Unfortunately, I found no docs about that, which is quite surprising.

Comment: The question is about backwards compatibility, i.e. can you run software that has been built for .NET 6 on the .NET 7 runtime. Of course, if you target an older version of .NET and rebuild then your software should run just fine, so long as you haven't used any of the newer language features available to the later versions. If your app targets .NET 7, it won't run unless the .NET 7 runtime is available.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that .NET7 program can reference and run .NET6 assemblies just fine.  I had the same question when looking for .NET7 DevExpress assemblies.  They don't exist yet DevExpress states that .NET7 is fully supported.  It is a shame that we cannot get a definitive answer from MS.  But vendor such as DevExpress has "a more direct line" to MS, so my guess is that it is actually backward compatible.

Comment: I think DevExpress is a niche example and doesn't really represent coverage over the entire SDK, so while DevExpress may work it doesn't mean everything will. The chart on the page I linked to covers areas that are binary compatible that will just work. There are also source compatible which means code changes would be required to get it to compile on the new version. All-in-all there are only a small handful of bits that are binary and source compatible with most falling under one or the other. There are some which are also not compatible at all.

Comment: The [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/7.0) indicates all the breaking changes in .Net 7.  There are about 70 of them across the whole .net framework.  I would say the majority of source and binary are backward compatible.

Comment: But not at the same time most are one of the other but not both. Also, saying .NET Framework is confusing as that already refers to the OG .NET. You should probably say .NET SDK instead.

Comment: I like your answer and found the link you referenced in the comment useful. I recommend making that a part of your answer.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell:

You can use net7.0 as a tool chain. However, using it as a runtime seems to have issues with running apps with a net6.0 target framework.

My recommendations are:

- Use net7.0 as a tool chain if you want.
- Use net6.0 as a framework target.
- Use net6.0 as a runtime in production.
- Use "self-contained" if you don't want to have the runtime side-loaded.
- When net8.0 comes out, wait a month, and upgrade both your tool chain and runtimes in production.

Comment: I'd broadly agree, but based on past experience, I'd give it more than a month :)